# How to use Server 2012 WDS advanced multicast features?

Tags: windows-server-2012, wds, multicast

First, can I be clear that I already know how to multicast, and using that without a problem.

What I would like to know is... how to use the **"Improved Multicast Features"** that are new for Server 2012 using WDS?

> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn281955
>
> **Improved multicast deployment** by *eliminating the need for making a local copy of the install.wim file.* You can apply the install.wim file while it is being downloaded without significant impact to the application process.

We have installed Server 2012, with WDS role and have multicast working (Windows 7 deployments). However, we do NOT see this improved feature being used at all. Multicast happens in exactly the same way as it did in Server 2008.

I can find no reference on how to utilise this improved feature correctly.

Comment: I would like to know this too. This would be a great time saver! Does it have to do with MDT? MDT has a special deployment client that it uses and might have that feature if you pair it with WDS...

Comment: The article is talking about Server 2012, of which WDS is a Role. MDT is a separate installation, and the article doesn't mention MDT, so I assume this feature does not depend on MDT!

Comment: It could. I personally think that to use this feature that you need to use them together because MDT has the advanced function required for operations like what you want to do...

Comment: Until there is a document outlining this, then I'll assume it's regarding WDS only, considering that's how the article is written :P

Comment: I can't find anything after googling everywhere.

Comment: I am going to assume that it automatically does it when multicasting.

Comment: I assumed the same, but it doesn't do it under my testing (you can monitor the drive that it is multicasting to - it still needs to expand the files once mcast is completed).